# Save entities using Spring Data JPA saveAll method even in exception scenario

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is there any way to save the true entities in the DB even after any exception occurred during `saveAll` execution?

For example, I have 100 entities and 2 entities result in `data violation exception` but I still want to save the other 98 entities in DB. As of now if a data violation exception occurred it save none in the DB.

```java
@Autowired
BillingJpaRepository billingJpaRepository;

@Transactional
private void saveBillingRecords(List<BillingInfo> billingInfos) {
    try {
        billingJpaRepository.saveAll(billingInfos);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException dataIntegrityViolationException) {
        this.saveBillingRecordsIndividually(billingInfos);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}

@Transactional
private void saveBillingRecordsIndividually(List<BillingInfo> billingInfos) {
    for(BillingInfo billingInfo : billingInfos) {
        try {
            billingJpaRepository.save(billingInfo);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException dataIntegrityViolationException) {
            logger.error("data voilation exception occured");  
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;  
        }
    }
}
```

Because of this, I have to save all true entities individually which is a performance hit. Since all the entities will be in detached stated after `saveAll` it will execute `merge` operation instead of `persist` and because of this, an extra `SELECT` statement will be triggered for each `save` operation. Below is my entity structure

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name= "BLI_INFO")
public class BillingInfo implements Persistable<long> {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "BLI_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "BLI_ID_SEQ", name = "id_gen", allocationSize = 1)
    private long billingId;

    ...
    // rest of the fields
    ...

    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = true;

    @PrePersist
    @PostLoad
    void markNotNew() {
        this.isNew = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew(){
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You will need to do individual inserts. A transaction is all or nothing, the saveAll is executed in a single transaction so everything succeeds or everything fails.